# Solving differential equations by the Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I need some help on solving the following differential equations by Frobenius method. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you!
$$1.)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~zu'+(1+z)u=0 $$
$$2.)~~~~~ u''−2u'+\left(1+\frac{1}{4z^2}\right)u=0 $$

Comment: In which part of the solution did you got stuck? (That would make easier to not give a hint in some part of the problem that you had already did.)

Comment: The first equation has a regular singular point at $z=0$ so take $u(z) = \frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{n-1}$ insert in the ODE and put it on the form $\sum[\cdots]z^{n} = 0$ for which $[\cdots] = 0$ will give you a simple recursion relation for $a_n$.